# ElseIf options for calculated fields?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date-time

I'm trying to calculate a date column based on what data exists in two other date columns. Is that possible?

Basically, in 95% of cases, the Planned Date is always 5 days from the Submission Date. I need the option to override that for the remaining 5% of cases.

```
if(subDate = null), planDate = ""
elseIf (subDate != null & overDate = null), planDate = subDate+5
elseIf (subDate != null & overDate != null), planDate = overDate
```

Here is what I have so far...
planDate =

```
IF(AND(ISBLANK([overDate]),[subDate]>1/1/1),DATE(YEAR([subDate])+0,MONTH([subDate])+0,DAY([subDate])+35),[overDate])
```

The problem is this misses a use case so it populates planDate with "12/30/1899" when both are null. I guess 12/30/1899 is the default.

Am I missing something obvious here? Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the conditions you mentioned in your question, use formula like below:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([subDate]),"",IF(ISBLANK([overDate]),[subDate]+5,[overDate]))
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14))

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another nested `IF` within the `ELSE`, and also and extra `ISBLANK` check for `subdate` before the other conditions

```
IF(
    ISBLANK([subDate])
    ,""
    ,IF(AND(ISBLANK([overDate]), [subDate]>1/1/1)
        , DATE(YEAR([subDate])+0,MONTH([subDate])+0,DAY([subDate])+5)
        , IF(AND([overDate]>1/1/1, [subDate]>1/1/1)
            , [overDate]
            , ""
        )       
    )
 )
```